# django admin hierarchical inline model edit

Tags: django, django-admin

Consider a wiki application. There is a model `Page`, that has many `Revision`s and each revision has many `block`s.

What is the simplest way to create an admin in which, you select a page and all the blocks of the latest revision appear; bonus points for letting change of revision by a dropdown (which is by default, sorted in reverse order anyway)

Is it absolutely necessary to create views, or can I extend some of those StackedInline forms, override `save` and mention some magic meta options, to get it all done automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this (in `admin.py`):

```
class RevInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Revision

class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Page
    inlines = (RevInline,)

admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

Comment: Yes, Something like this is what I have got. But I want blocks displayed. Each revision has many blocks associated with it. So, essentially, I select page, I need all the blocks associated with the latest revision of the page